# Getting an error when making a simple app that uses SQL

Tags: c#, winforms

The error says:

> The model backing the 'DB' context has changed since the database was created

I am doing the same thing my teacher did but I'm getting this error.

This is my `Student` class :

```
namespace WinFormsApp_project2
{
    public class std
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string fname { get; set; }
        public int age { get; set; }
        public int mark { get; set; }
        public int student_id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And my `DbContext` :

```
namespace WinFormsApp_project2
{
    public class DB : DbContext
    {
        public DB() : base("name=constr1") { }
        public DbSet<std> students { set; get; }
    }
}
```

Main program:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    std s1 = new std();
    s1.name = name.Text;
    s1.fname = fname.Text;
    s1.age = Convert.ToInt32(age.Text);
    s1.mark = Convert.ToInt32(mark.Text);
    s1.student_id = Convert.ToInt32(std_id.Text);

    if (MessageBox.Show("اضافه کردن به لیست دانش آموزان ؟", "ثبت نام", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        if (s1.age < 18)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("سن دانش آموز کم تر از 18 است", "خطا", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            age.Focus();

        }
        else
        {
            // adds to the list
            DB db1 = new DB();
            db1.students.Add(s1); // this is were i get an error

            db1.SaveChanges();

            if (s1.mark < 10)
            {
                //ads to the list of failed students
                stds_fail.Add(s1);
            }
            MessageBox.Show("با موفقیت انجام شد", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = db1.students.ToList();
            dataGridView2.DataSource = null;
            dataGridView2.DataSource = stds_fail;
            foreach (var item in Controls)
            {
                if (item.GetType().ToString() == "System.Windows.Forms.TextBox")
                {
                    (item as TextBox).Clear();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        name.Focus();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the structure of the database table?